# How to place image on left side of a table in HTML5

Tags: html, image, html-table

I am using `HTML5`.
I want to have a page in which, it has a image and table side by side
Means,

we can consider `<table>`

In which, I have a `<tr>.`

In `<tr>`, I have 2 `<td></td>`

In one `<td>`,I want to display an image and in another`<td>`,

I want to display a `<table>` having some fields.

But it is not displaying properly.

second `<td>` data is displaying below the first `<td>`
my scenario is like:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <image src=""></image>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                field1
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                textbox
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                field 2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                textbox
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                button
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Screen is displaying like this:
[image]

how can I do this?

Updated:
My ASP.NET MVC View:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="width: auto; height: auto;">
                        <image src="../../Images/Image1.jpg"></image>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="width: auto; height: auto;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                                                    Application1
                                                                            </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful.")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <%: Html.LocalizedLabelFor(m => m.LoginID)%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginID)%><br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <%: Html.LocalizedLabelFor(m => m.Password)%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)%><br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                                            <td>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Log On"
                                                    name="Login"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that the table in your second `td` is showing below the image? I just checked your markup, the image and the table are infact side by side, like this `image|table`

Comment: I mean to say that image is displaying correctly and to the right side of image it is displaying table but below the image. I have added scenario of my screen which is displaying wrongly

Comment: To upload image: edit -> then hit ctrl-g, you will get a prompt.

Comment: Are you sure you have put in the html markup that is causing you problem in your question because I cannot find anything wrong with it.

Comment: Yes am sure. I have added scenario also. I want table on the right side of image, and not below the image

Comment: I used your markup and see the result here http://imgur.com/izDsVLG You see, it is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is because,you have placed just a text. i have actual textbox like:  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)%>. am using it in ASP.NET MVC project

Comment: It should not matter. Post the asp.net mvc markup.

Comment: I have added the ASP.NET markup in my question

Comment: I have tried with your markup too, it is correct. Have you inspected the html generated? Post the html generated when you run the website.

Comment: I have added my actual page view

Comment: When the page is loaded in the browser, right click and do View Source, then check that html. If you can't find the issue there, post that html in the question.

Comment: Give your `<td>` with the submit button a `colspan="2"`